Unable to import face_recognition
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition' after installing dlib, cmake, and face_recognition"
I am trying to use the face_recognition library in Python, but I keep getting the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Installed cmake:
pip install cmake

Installed dlib:
pip install dlib

Installed face_recognition:
pip install face_recognition


The installations seem to go through without any errors, but when I try to import face_recognition in my Python script, I get the ModuleNotFoundError. I have already checked the following:

Verified that face_recognition is installed using pip list, and it shows up in the list.
Checked that I'm using the correct Python environment by running which python and which pip.
Tried reinstalling the face_recognition module multiple times.

Here is the environment I'm working with:

OS: Windows 11
Python version: Python 3.12.5
Installed via: pip

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. What could be the cause of this error despite the successful installation of the necessary packages?

This question is similar to: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you forgot to take the [tour]. -- is there any PyCharm involved? any virtual environments? even those you are unaware of?

I am using VS code and yes there is a virtual environment

face_recognition package doesn't officially support Windows. If you have choice, try running it on Linux or Mac.
If you only have Windows, you can try this guide. Comparing to your description, author has additionally installed Visual Studio with C++ compiler and Boost.

thanks for responding. I have only option of windows
